# How can I iterate over an object in a forEach loop with correctly typed values and parameters?

Tags: typescript

I have created an interface called `Profile` for my profile object. Now, I intend to make a function for updating the values of this object, among other things. To achieve this, I have defined a type called `UpdateProfileParams`, which includes a partial object. This type works precisely as needed.

```
export interface Profile {
  page: number
  pageSize: number
  columnsWidth: number[]
  selectedRowsKeys: string[]
}
```

```
export type UpdateProfileParams = {
  [Param in keyof Profile]?: Profile[Param]
}
```

I've created an `updateProfile` function within a React component. However, I encountered an issue where TypeScript is returning parameter keys as `string` instead of the `keyof` my object type. The type of the value is true, but it's as extensive as a condition for all possibilities.

```
  const updateProfile = useCallback(
    (params: UpdateProfileParams): void => {
      _.forEach(params, (value, param): void => {
        //eslint-disable-next-line
        //@ts-ignore
        profile.current[param] = value
      })
    },
    []
  )
```

How can I iterate over an object in a `forEach` loop with correctly typed values and parameters, without resorting to workarounds like `as` or other specific method to validate type? Is there a proper TypeScript solution to resolve this issue?

Error message:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Profile'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Profile'
```

Comment: Please [edit] the code so that it's a [mre] without reference to external or private code like `_` or `useCallback` or `profile`.  If the question actually depends on these, then you should define/declare/import them and tag the question accordingly (lodash, react, etc).  Right now if we copy and paste your code into our own IDEs we get various errors you're not asking about, which makes it harder to get started.